# Groupwise max mysql query ignores NULL columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table with cars. Each car has a unique `id`, and other car stat-related columns. I want to display top 10 fastest cars. If a car has the same Trim + ModelID + MakeID, I want to show only the newest car.

Example:

```
Year Make    Model  Trim  Time060
--------------------------------
2017 Bugatti Chiron null  2.3
2018 Bugatti Chiron null  2.3
```

My problem is that if Trim is null, neither 2017 nor 2018 shows up. If the trims are not null and are the same, I correctly get the 2018 car.

Here is the query that I have:

```
 SELECT stats.* 
   FROM stats 
NATURAL 
   JOIN
      ( SELECT MakeID
             , ModelID
             , Trim
             , MAX(Year) AS Year 
          FROM stats 
         GROUP 
            BY Trim
             , ModelID
             , MakeID
      ) t
  ORDER 
     BY Time060 
  LIMIT 10
```

I've tried using `...(SELECT MakeID, ModelID, IFNULL(Trim, 'temp_trim') AS Trim, MAX(Year) AS Year FROM stats GROUP BY Trim, ModelID, MakeID)...`, but that doesn't work as well.

Comment: did you try `GROUP BY IFNULL(Trim, 'temp_trim'), ModelID, MakeID` ?

Comment: Just tried, did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` and the *null safe equal to operator* [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) to check for the equality of `NULL`s:

```
select s.* from stats s
where not exists (
  select 1 from stats
  where makeid = s.makeid and modelid = s.modelid and trim <=> s.trim and year > s.year
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qyRyyFVnJu6yhmk4XzYAKC/2).

Or:

```
select s.* from stats s
where s.year = (
  select max(year) 
  from stats
  where makeid = s.makeid and modelid = s.modelid and trim <=> s.trim
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qyRyyFVnJu6yhmk4XzYAKC/4).
Or with a join:

```
select s.* 
from stats s inner join (
  select makeid, modelid, trim, max(year) year
  from stats
  group by makeid, modelid, trim
) t on t.makeid = s.makeid and t.modelid = s.modelid and t.trim <=> s.trim and t.year = s.year
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qyRyyFVnJu6yhmk4XzYAKC/5).
Since you are interested in performance check another option if your version of MySql/MariaDB supports window functions:

```
select t.year, t.makeid, t.modelid, t.trim, t.time060
from (
  select s.*,
    row_number() over (partition by makeid, modelid, trim order by year) rn
  from stats s  
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nEpeWvJ862ukaSR67iDPim/3).

Comment: Just tried the first one and it worked! Thanks a lot. Do you know which one of the options that you've provided has better performance?

Comment: This depends on the data that you have. I believe that for a large table the 3d query with a composite index on makeid, modelid, trim would do better. But my personal preference is EXISTS and NOT EXISTS which is always the 1st way that I try. There are case that EXISTS performs better because it returns as soon as it finds or not the condition.

Comment: Check another option with window function ROW_NUMBER().